# Installing matplotlib on Mac OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I am trying to install matplotlib but facing many problems. I am receiving a common error from both pip install matplotlib as well as trying to build from source which is:

```
BUILDING MATPLOTLIB

        matplotlib: 1.1.1

            python: 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33)  [GCC 4.2.1

                    Compatible Apple Clang 4.0

                    (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)]

          platform: darwin
```

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES

```
             numpy: 1.6.1

                    * Could not find the headers for numpy.  You may

                    * need to install the development package.
```

EDIT: Solved it finally. I needed to install gfortran and gcc compilers. Did it using brew and everything worked like a charm!

Comment: Building from source should ok (at least with a recent version from git). But you need to make sure numpy's header files are in the linker path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it finally. I needed to install gfortran and gcc compilers. Did it using brew and everything worked like a charm!

Comment: How did you install gcc and fortran? I found gfortran in brew, but not gcc? Also, did you install matplotlib directly afterwards or did you have to `pip install --upgrade numpy`first?

Comment: @kermit666 it is there in brew

Comment: Thanks, @Peter. Maybe a year too late, though :) This is the tutorial that worked for me: http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/

Answer (score 4):

Installing matplotlib on Mountain Lion requires to install the development version of matplotlib.

Try `pip install git+https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git#egg=matplotlib-dev`

You may need `numpy 1.6.2` for it to work.

Generally, for Mountain Lion, you can find great advices and a well described step-by-step procedure to install numpy/scipy/matplotlib/IPhython at [this link](http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/)

Comment: You probably want to pin it to the latest tag that works on mac: ``git+git://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git@v1.1.1@egg=matplotlib``

Answer (score 0):

macports or brew is the best way for such things on mac.My experience

Answer (score -1):

Install numpy.

```
pip install numpy
```

It should sort out dependencies for you - I'm not sure why it is not working.

Comment: I have numpy already. Anyway, I tried it again and it says requirements are satisfied. Just tried with numpy

Comment: Did you install the numpy-dev package?